# Why std.RedBlackTree as a map breaks?

Tags: d

I finally decided to use `std.RedBlackTree` instead of the built-in associative arrays (or hash) because I need a sorted associative array.  The desired behavior pretty much similar to `std::map` in C++/STL.

```
void main() {

  alias Tuple!(float, float) Pair;
  alias RedBlackTree!Pair Map;
  Map m1;
  m1.insert(Pair(1.1, 2.2));
}
```

The above code, depending on how you compile it (with or without -release), will cause segmentation fault or will throw assertion.

Same thing with this:

```
void main() {

  struct Pair { float first, second; }
  alias RedBlackTree!(Pair, "a.first < b.first") Map;
  Map m1;
  m1.insert(Pair(1.1, 2.2));
}
```

Smells like a bug, but is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RedBlackTree is a class and, as such, must be initialized. m1 defaults to null. What you're seeing is the equivalent of a NullPointerException in Java.

Try this:

```
import std.stdio, std.container;
void main() {
  struct Pair { float first, second; }
  alias RedBlackTree!(Pair, "a.first < b.second") Map;
  Map m1 = new Map;
  m1.insert(Pair(1.1, 2.2));
}
```

Also, as an aside tip for this programming example: You might want to consider `RedBlackTree!(Pair, "a.first < b.first")` instead. The reason is that it would have some strange (not quite undefined, but probably not what you want) behavior.

For instance, `Pair(1, 2) < Pair(1, 3)` would be true. Oddly, `Pair(1, 3) < Pair(1, 2)` would also be true.

Comment: I was under the impression that `RedBlackTree` was a struct because `Array` is a struct, lol.  Also, `a.first < b.second` was a typo and I fixed it.

Comment: As a side note, DMD should flag such thing as an error.  I mean, there is no way to tell if a type is a class or not without the source code or the docs, is there?

Comment: Not that I know of. Generally speaking, I'm using the docs while I code if I'm not familiar with whatever I'm working with... but the "AssertError ... null this" (when I don't compile with the -release flag) is usually the way I find out that I mistook a class for a struct.

Comment: @Arlen D couldn't flag this except in the most basic cases, and the segfault shows you exactly where the problem is. I think that it's pretty much expected that you know whether the type that you're using is a class or a struct (you need to, because it affects a number of things about how the type is used), and would think that it's perfectly reasonable to expect that anyone using a type or function has either the documentation or the source. And the fact that you get a segfault when using `.` should be a huge red flag that the item on the left-hand side is probably `null`.

Answer (score 3):

I would point out that the first two things that you should generally look for when you get a segfault are null pointers/references and infinite recursion. And you can use a debugger to determine exactly where they occur.

`RedBlackTree` is a class and therefore any variable which is a `RedBlackTree` is a reference type. So, you have to assign it a value other than `null`, or it will be `null`, and you'll get a segfault when you try and use it. The exact same thing will happen if you have a variable which was a pointer to something, and you tried to use it without assigning it a non-null value.

Your initialization line should be

```
Map m1 = new Map;
```

Alternatively, with `RedBlackTree`, you could do

```
Map m1 = redBlackTree!"a.first < b.first"(Pair(1.1, 2.2));
```

[`redBlackTree`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_container#redBlackTree) is a helper function for creating and inserting elements into a `RedBlackTree` in one line.